# React Router/ createContext hook, chicken-and-egg situation with JWT

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-router

So I have a CRA based react app with a node/express back end that uses a JWT for authentication. the JWT is generated on signup and set to localstorage from the front end.

The problem I have is with my navigation I believe. When the token expires or is cleared the user is redirected to the login page but the way I have wrapped my routes in context providers is preventing access to the login page because there is no token yet.

index.js

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```js
 return (
      <div>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <GlobalStyle />
          <Router history={history}>
            <UsersContextProvider>
              <VehiclesContextProvider>
                <CampaignsContextProvider>
                  <Switch>
                    <ErrorBoundary>
                      {alert.message && (
                        <div className={`alert ${alert.type}`}>
                          {alert.message}
                        </div>
                      )}

                      <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                        <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
                          <PrivateRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                          <PrivateRoute
                            path="/dashboard"
                            component={Dashboard}
                          />
                          <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
                          <PrivateRoute
                            path="/campaignlist"
                            component={CampaignList}
                          />
                          <PrivateRoute
                            path="/saleslist"
                            component={SalesList}
                          />
                          <Route
                            exact
                            path="/login"
                            component={SignInAndSignUpPage}
                          />
                        </Suspense>
                      </PersistGate>
                    </ErrorBoundary>
                  </Switch>
                </CampaignsContextProvider>
              </VehiclesContextProvider>
            </UsersContextProvider>
          </Router>
        </ThemeProvider>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

The error I get is:

```js
TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'token' of 'JSON.parse(...)' as it is null.
UsersContextProvider
src/context/UsersContextProvider.js:9
   6 | const UsersContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
   7 |   const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);
   8 | 
>  9 |   const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  10 |   // console.log('token', token);
  11 |   const getUsersData = async () => {
  12 |     const users = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}users?sort=createdAt`, {
```

All of my context providers are similar to this one:

```js
const UsersContext = createContext();
const UsersContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([]);

  const { token } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
  // console.log('token', token);
  const getUsersData = async () => {
    const users = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}users?sort=createdAt`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${token}` },
    });
    // console.log('usersData', users.data.data);
    setUsersData(users.data.data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getUsersData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <UsersContext.Provider value={{ usersData }}>
      {children}
    </UsersContext.Provider>
  );
```

I have tried getting the token in various components including the app.js and passing it around to children components, also thought of creating a new context provider where all I do is get the token and pass it down but that seemed a little verbose for just a token and not even sure it will work.

I am pretty sure that there should be a much easier and cleaner way of handling this but can't quite figure out how.

Another thought I had was to somehow separate the login route so it's not in the scope of all the providers and such but can't find any information I would do that with a setup like mine.

Does anyone have any pointers for me please?

TIA!

Comment: `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))` will return `null` if the key is missing/not present in local storage, so you should do a null check before trying to access the return value/object. This won't help with the issue of only checking authentication when the `UsersContextProvider` mounts though, for this you'll need a different mechanism to listen to local storage or move to something like Redux and keep it in app state (persisted to local storage OFC). This will help keep your auth "state" in sync.

Comment: You could create two routes, e.g. /public/ and /private/, then mount the Context only on the /private/ routes.